# ASP.NET + IIS6: whitelist users via authorization section in web.config

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-6, web-config, authorization

Consider an IIS6 Application under a web site:

- Windows authentication is enabled.
- anonymous is off

This is an ASP.NET MVC application with Areas. The root web.config has the authentication and authorization nodes as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>

<authorization> 
    <allow users="domain\abc, domain\xyz, domain\foo, domain\bar"/>   
</authorization>
```

My identity is NOT in the list of allowed users. Entering the URL in the browser, I can view and navigate to all the pages within. I know I am being authorized properly, as my Active Directory name is displayed on the site.

**Problem:** I am given access to the site.

**Question:** Using the web.config, how can I restrict users based on their Windows credentials to this IIS6 Application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<authorization> 
    <allow users="domain\abc, domain\xyz, domain\foo, domain\bar"/>   
    <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a deny section behind the allow one?

```
<deny users="*" />
```